# How to load and work with tensorflow reddit dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, reddit

I need to work with the tldr reddit dataset for text summarization.

I thought it would be straightforward to load the dataset as follows:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('reddit', split = 'train')
```

But I am met with an ExtractionError that says no space left on this device (the device is a university cluster).

Is there a workaround for this? How can I load and work with this dataset? I can't find anything on the net for this dataset. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dataset is 18 GB, you could well not have enough space, for example if you hit some quota limits. You should ask your sysadmins to help you in that case.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you for your comment. Is there a way, I could work with a chunk of this dataset, maybe 5GB..as in a way of loading only that much of this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this above code using [Google Colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb), where you can have `12 GB RAM` and `108 GB Disk space` for free to use.